# Dynamic Query Param

Tags: rest, jersey

I have requirement where Query Param name is not fixed. i.e.

> /Test/Add?a=b,c&a1=b1,c1
>
> /Test/Add?d=e,f&c1=d1,f1

I have read in some article saying use @Context URI, HttpServlerRequest.

Can you please guide me how to implement this in Jersey?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add the [UriInfo](http://jersey.java.net/nonav/apidocs/1.8/jersey/javax/ws/rs/core/UriInfo.html) to your class like this:

```java
public class Example {
  @Context
  UriInfo uriInfo;

  @GET
  @Path("/")
  public void get() {
    System.out.println(uriInfo.getPathParameters());
  }
}
```